# Save token and use it on post request nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I 'm making a node project and i 'm having trouble when i try to use token result for get request and use it in another get.. 
how can i use?
thanks!

this is my code:

app.js

```
.get('/api/v1/token', tokenController.getToken)

.get('/api/v1/search', searchController.getSearch)
```

Tokencontroller.js

```
const eventService = require('../services/eventService')

function getToken(req, res){
     eventService.getToken()
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.body)
        const token = response.body.access
        console.log(token)
        res.send(token)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('token error')
        next(error)
    }) 
}

module.exports = {getToken}
```

eventService.js

```
    module.exports = {

      getToken() {
          return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var payload = {
              username: 'jon@mail.com',
              password: "1111",
              grant_type: 'password',
            };

            request.post({
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer.from('user-one' + ':' + '000000000').toString('base64'),
                'Accept': 'application/json'
              },
              url: 'myurl/oauth/token',
              form: payload
            }, function (error, response, body) {
              if (error) {
                reject(error)
              } else {
                resolve({ response , body })
              }
            });
          })
      }
```

now i got the token and i need to pass it to getSearch ..
token response:

```
{"access_token":"123456","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"12345"}
```

searchController.js

```
function getSearch(req, res){

   eventService.getSearch()
    .then(response => {      
        res.send(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        next(error)
    })
}
```

eventService getSearch

```
 getSearch() {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      request.post({
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + '123456' //==> token access_token propertie
        },
        url: 'myurlcontent/search',
      }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error)
        } else {
          resolve({ response, body })
        } 
      });
    }) 
  }
```

Comment: Are you sending the token to front-end ?

Comment: Hey Darshana! no i'm not..

Comment: I'm trying to do that but i when i try to uses on header from getSearch dosen 't work.. i think i'm doing someting wrong..

Comment: there you are using token as a text. that is not a variable

Comment: you are mentioning `token`. is that your variable or just a placeholder for an example ?

Comment: oh only for answer me.. `token` is and example

Comment: Can you edit the question ?. Actually what you are doing there ?. I need to see that

Comment: Darshana ..i edited just now